# How to get current Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've a VBA function:

```
public function MyFunction(someParameters) as Double

  ... do something ...

  return aValue

end function
```

I've a sheet where my function is called from some cells:

```
A1: =MyFunction(...) 

A2: =MyFunction(...)

A100: =MyFunction(..)
```

I would like to return a value (and it works) AND also to add a comment to the cell...

If I use `ActiveCell` and then I use `AddComment`, it add comment to the last cell I left my cursor, not the 'active cell calculated'.

How to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You can reference the cell which calls the UDF - I haven't tried that for adding comments, though. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/379635-get-cell-reference-udf-caller.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that using `ActiveCell`. Your function recalculates and everytime it's called ActiveCell is something different (depending on selection). The logic for adding comments via UDF seems a bit flawed  but you may try this

```
Public Function MyFunction() As Double

    MyFunction = 3.141519

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range(Application.Caller.Address)

    cell.AddComment (cell.Address)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Application.Caller`, not `ActiveCell`.

e.g.

```
Function Test() As String
    Test = Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687%28v=office.15%29.aspx